# How to get list of boundary points after mesh triangulations

Tags: python, geometry, computational-geometry

I need the list of those points circled in black.

However, `mesh.points` gives all points.

Could you suggest a popular library for easy mesh generation that supports this feature?

I tried `add_boundary_layer` but I didn't find any attribute with such data.

[image]

```
    import numpy as np
    import pygmsh
    with pygmsh.geo.Geometry() as geom:
        poly  = geom.add_polygon(
            # points,
            [[0.0, 0.0],
            [1.0, -0.2],
            [1.1, 1.2],
            [0.1, 0.7],],
            mesh_size=0.2,
        )
        field0 = geom.add_boundary_layer(
            edges_list=[poly.curves[0]],
            lcmin=5,
            lcmax=0.4,
            distmin=5,
            distmax=0.2,
        )
        # geom.set_background_mesh([field0], operator="Min")
        mesh = geom.generate_mesh()
        print("done")
    #     plot matplotlib
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.triplot(mesh.points[:, 0], mesh.points[:, 1], mesh.cells[1].data)
        ax.axis('auto')
        plt.pause(0.1)
        plt.show()
```